# facebook and twitter buttons doesn't work

Tags: html, css, facebook, twitter, web

I am building a website in dreamweaver cs5. for some reason, the facebook like button and twitter share as well as follow button doesn't work. facebook like button shows nothing. (in the area, chrome says page cannot be found), twitter buttons show the hyperlink tweet and it tweets but the icon doesn't show up. The code for both are generated from facebook and twitter itself.

I haven't hosted the site yet. I and coding and previewing it. Is that the reason for them not to work?

I also tried addthis.com widget. It didn't show up as it should have.

Please help!
Many thanks.

Comment: If you did that manually, without dreamweaver, you would answer it yourself easily...

Comment: It's impossible to debug something we cannot see; include the source and maybe someone will be able to spot the problem.

Comment: @zermsks I tried it using notepad.. Here's the code i tried in notpad:

<html>
<head </head>
<body>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FKIck-Ass-Sport%2F294340553936065&amp;width=500&amp;height=427&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:427px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

The result is the same. The page cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter button will function but not show up and Facebook button not render at all if the site is not on a reachable host, i.e. if u run it from your local server which is not accessible from the Internet. Hope this helps.